# Mostrar conteúdo dum dicionário em modo ordenado segundo os valores

Tags: python-3.x

Estou a tentar encontrar maneiras de ordenar um dicionário segundo os valores, para depois mostrar as chaves. A maneira melhor que encontrei até agora é a seguinte:

```
import operator

def mostra_ordenado_por_valores(dic={}):
    if len(dic) > 0:
        for k, v in sorted(dic.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1)): # sorts by values
            print("Key:",k,"\tValue:",v)

months = {'January':31,'February':28,'March':31,'April':30,'May':31,'June':30,
'July':31,'August':31,'September':30,'October':31,'November':30,'December':31}

mostra_ordenado_por_valores(months)
```

E o output é o seguinte:

```
Key: February   Value: 28
Key: November   Value: 30
Key: September  Value: 30
Key: April      Value: 30
Key: June       Value: 30
Key: July       Value: 31
Key: October    Value: 31
Key: March      Value: 31
Key: December   Value: 31
Key: January    Value: 31
Key: August     Value: 31
Key: May        Value: 31
```

Gostaria de saber se existe outra maneira de o fazer sem usar o modulo `operator`.

Comment: Você não quer importar o `operator`, é isso?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar um OrderedDict.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
months = {'January':31,'February':28,'March':31,'April':30,'May':31,'June':30, 'July':31,'August':31,'September':30,'October':31,'November':30,'December':31}
months_ordered = OrderedDict(sorted(months.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]))

for k, v in months_ordered.items():
    print('Key: {0} \t Value: {1}'.format(k,v))
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar um *construct* chamado **lambda** para criar uma função anônima:

```
sorted(months.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])
```